# How do I disable a static block on my home page?

Tags: static-block, cms-block, cms-pages

This one has me baffled.

I have a static block situated at the bottom of my home page and just above the footer labelled. The static block is titled ‘Recommended’.

It is a sliding product block and I can not find it listed in my static blocks in admin/cms/static_blocks in order to disable is and I can also not find the code in my HOME page CMS content that is calling the block.

Below is an image of the block and below that is the code from the HOME page CMS.

You can see that the static block is located below three images 1) Free UK Delivery, 2) Fast Worldwide Delivery, 3) Easy Returns, all of which are the last piece of code in my HOME page CMS content.

No other code comes after the code for these and so I am baffled as to where the static block code is being called from for the ‘Recommended’ block.

[image: screenshot of static block]

```
<div style="background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 25px;">
<div class="nested-container">
<div class="page-banners grid-container">
<div class="grid12-4 mobile-grid banner fade-on-hover hide-below-768"><a title="men’s boxer briefs and trunks" href="{{store direct_url="mens-underwear/mens-underwear-styles/boxers-trunks.html"}}"> <img title="Men’s Boxer Briefs and Trunks" alt="Men’s Boxer Briefs and Trunks" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/top_images/boxers.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="grid12-4 mobile-grid banner fade-on-hover hide-below-768"><a title="Men’s Thongs and Strings" href="{{store direct_url="mens-underwear/mens-underwear-styles/thongs-strings.html"}}"> <img title="Men’s Thongs and Strings" alt="Men’s Thongs and Strings" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/top_images/thongs.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="grid12-4 mobile-grid banner fade-on-hover hide-below-768"><a title="Men’s Briefs" href="{{store direct_url="mens-underwear/mens-underwear-styles/mens-briefs-tangas.html"}}"> <img title="Men’s Briefs" alt="Men’s Briefs" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/top_images/briefs.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
</div>
</div>
<!– 2 Products Slider – Small Images –>
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="98" product_count="12" breakpoints="[0, 4]" timeout="8000" move="4" centered="1" size="size-m" hide_button="0" img_width="150" block_name="Featured Boxers"}}
<div style="background-color: #fafafa;">
<div class="container">
<div class="inner-container"><br />
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Our Featured Designer Brands</h2>
<br />
<p style="font-size: 16px; color: #999999; line-height: 23px; text-align: center;">At Giggleberries we go to great lengths to bring your only the very best in designer men’s underwear and swimwear. These are just a taste of the wonderfully distinct and fashionable brands in designer underwear and beachwear we offer.</p>
</div>
<br />
<div class="nested-container">
<div class="page-banners grid-container">
<div class="grid12-3 mobile-grid banner fade-on-hover"><a title="Clever Moda Underwear" href="{{store direct_url="mens-underwear/mens-underwear-brands/clever-moda-underwear.html"}}"> <img title="Clever Moda Underwear" alt="Clever Moda Underwear" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/bottom_images/home_bottom_image1.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="grid12-3 mobile-grid banner fade-on-hover"><a title="Manstore Underwear" href="{{store direct_url="mens-underwear/mens-underwear-brands/manstore-underwear.html"}}"> <img title="Manstore Underwear" alt="Manstore Underwear" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/bottom_images/home_bottom_image2.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="grid12-3 mobile-grid banner fade-on-hover"><a title="Pikante Underwear" href="{{store direct_url="mens-underwear/mens-underwear-brands/pikante-underwear.html"}}"> <img title="Pikante Underwear" alt="Pikante Underwear" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/bottom_images/home_bottom_image3.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="grid12-3 mobile-grid banner fade-on-hover"><a title="Olaf Benz Underwear" href="{{store direct_url="mens-underwear/mens-underwear-brands/olaf-benz-underwear.html"}}"> <img title="Olaf Benz Underwear" alt="Olaf Benz Underwear" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/bottom_images/home_bottom_image4.jpg"}}" /> </a></div>
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="100" product_count="12" breakpoints="[0, 4]" timeout="6000" move="4" centered="1" size="size-m" hide_button="0" img_width="150" block_name="Featured Thongs"}}
<div class="nested-container" style="margin-top: 25px;"><!– First banner has a link which adds a product to the cart (link was copied from product’s button "Add to cart") –>
<div class="page-banners grid-container">
<div class="grid12-4 banner fade-on-hover hide-below-768"><a title="Free UK Delivery" href="{{store direct_url="delivery-and-returns"}}"> <img title="Free UK Delivery" alt="Free UK Delivery" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/bottom_images/banner01.png"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="grid12-4 banner fade-on-hover hide-below-768"><a title="Fast Worldwide Delivery" href="{{store direct_url="delivery-and-returns"}}"> <img title="Fast Worldwide Delivery" alt="Fast Worldwide Delivery" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/bottom_images/banner02.png"}}" /> </a></div>
<div class="grid12-4 banner fade-on-hover hide-below-768"><a title="Easy Returns" href="{{store direct_url="delivery-and-returns"}}"> <img title="Easy Returns" alt="Easy Returns" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/home_page/bottom_images/banner03.png"}}" /> </a></div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks
Jimbob

Comment: It sounds like this block is added via layout directly in the files and not via the backend. I suggest you enable the Template Path Hints as well as Block hints to find out. Under System > Configuration > Developer. Then change the Store Scope by selecting your store in the dropdown and enable both hints. Reload your page to find out

Comment: As above I believe this is added via XML, I don't think it is a static block. Off the top of my head I think it's located in Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml. If you search for the word related in there you should find the block, then you can remove it in your theme. I'm on my phone at the moment so I can't be 100% sure though

Comment: check your theme documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a path of template you could enable a path hint which helps you for which you can refer.

1) http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMcH8bOxoOw

And per as your question is concern please check once **CMS->Widget**. we can use a block in widget.

also check a layout xml's either **local.xml** or **custom extensions xml**.

Hope this will help you.